# How to make video loop properly?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to play this video in a loop https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm16617386 . I want to play an mp4 file in such a way, that whenever it gets to some point in the video (let's say, 30.3 seconds), it will loop back (to for example 5.85 seconds).

I tried to add this code in ffplay.c , it didn't work well enough, I can hear the transition. I guess seeking isn't fast enough, or audio needs to be looped in an independant way somehow.

```
static void video_refresh(void *opaque, double *remaining_time)
{
   (original code here...)
    time = get_master_clock(is);
    if (isnan(time))
        time = (double)is->seek_pos / AV_TIME_BASE;
    if (time > jump_when) {
        stream_seek(is, (int64_t)(6.0 * AV_TIME_BASE), (int64_t)(0.0 * AV_TIME_BASE), 0);
    }
}
```

My current plan is to just dig into ffmpeg, understand how video and audio decoders work, and savestate/loadstate the decoders.

Answer (score 1):

> - *"I want to play an mp4 file in such a way, that whenever it gets to some point in the video (eg: 30.3 seconds), it will loop back to earlier time (eg: 5.85 seconds)."*
> - *"I can hear the transition. I guess seeking isn't fast enough, or audio needs to be looped in an independent way somehow."*

Your linked video has a keyframe every 2 seconds (precisely 2.023). 
So you can only seek to seconds like 2.023, 4.023, 6.023, 8.023, etc.

If you want 5.850 seconds You need to first seek to the keyframe at 4 secs, then decode every next following frame up to required timestamp of 5.850. At this point you can then display video.

The solution I've used in the past was to simply adjust the timestamps (**PTS**) of the P/B frames to same as the keyframe before feeding their bytes to an H264 decoder. (This way the decoder is forced to fast-forward through the video to keep synchronization). I've used FFmpeg only within command line, so not sure how you can change display times in your shown code.

**Why?**:
In MPEG compression, you can **only seek to keyframes**. Every audio frame is a keyframe, but video has 3 types of frame: `I` (which is a keyframe or complete picture), there is also `P` and `B` frames (which have only small differences from main picture over time). These P/B frames need a *nearest previous* keyframe to be decoded **first** so they too have pixel data to show. P/B frames cannot be decoded by just themselves (since they're not complete image data).

Comment: Yeah, the code above already seeks to keyframes. I tell `stream_seek` to seek to 6 seconds, but it seeks somewhere to 5.1 instead. So instead of choosing "where" to jump, I'm choosing "from where" to jump, the `jump_when` variable. It seems that I can't get the right time to jump, the audio always 0.02 seconds slow or fast, can't align it properly. The jump happens in the video_refresh function, which is called 30 times per second, and this precision isn't enough it seems.